# is it possible to get struts tag by jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2

For html elements, to get a tag in jquery we use `$('tagname')`. Is this possible for strurs2 tags? 
Ex: If we are using `<sj:accordion >` how can we get all the `<sj:accordionItem >` 's

Answer (score 1):

No, You cannot select by your server side tags.. However you can select them by `class/id/traversing` those elements after they are rendered on your browser.

Your server side code will be compiled and generated as HTML before it is returned to the browser.. but your jQuery is on the client browser and initialized, used only after it is rendered on your browser.  and So it has no way of knowing how your server code is..

Comment: so, to apply scripts using jquery, dont we have a alternate solution except class? can you give me how i can traverse through these elements

Comment: @bhanuuday I have no knowledge on `sj` tags but I believe they had something like topic/subscribe concept allowing you to trigger specific code at any event..  I believe you would be doing the same by using jQuery selector.. If it is about modifying any HTML content / CSS updates.. then you can always look at the rendered code and locate them..

Comment: The subscribe would help me a bit. But is it good to look at rendered code and perform?

Comment: @bhanuuday Depends on what you are trying to do.. but yes.. most likely looking at rendered code will tell you how it is and what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all accordionItem-s by setting `id` attribute of `<sj:accordion>` tag (e.g. `<sj:accordion id="accord">`) and then in script `$("#accord li")`.